# Regex Expressão Regular - Incluir parenteses no lugar de aspas

Tags: regex

Como trocar as aspas por um tag? 
trabalhando para converter (*.dml ->formulário do delphi) onde algo que estava como texto passa a ser lista (stringlist).

Exemplo do Texto:

```
CommandText = 'SELECT * FROM PRODUTOS'
```

Queremos converter para

```
SQL.Text = ('SELECT * FROM PRODUTOS')
```

Observe que temos que incluir os parenteses de Inicio ( e fim ). Deixando as aspas.

Como poderia ser elaborado esta expressão do Regex 
OBS: Vou utilizar para fazer migração do TSimpleDataSet

Comment: Que linguagem você vai utilizar para fazer essa substituição?

Comment: Você quer somente substituir o conteúdo do command text por ele mesmo entre aspas ou quer mudar a sequência toda de command text =...  Para SQL.TEXT =...?

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço muito de Delphi, mas dei uma olhadinha. A regex parece ser simples se todas as suas variáveis tiverem esse nome (faltou mais exemplos).
`CommandText = '(.*)'`
O comando seria `TRegEx.Replace(string, 'CommandText = ''(.*)'' ', 'SQL.Text = (''\1'')')`
[Exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/tAH50Y/2)